# Fast 1D convolution with finite filter and sum of dirac deltas in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, convolution

I need to compute the following convolution:

[image]

And K is a very simple filter, that is simply a rectangular box with finite (!) size. 
My data is a list of the times t_i of the Dirac deltas.

The straightforward solution would be to bin the data and use one of numpy or scipys convolution functions. Yet, is there a quicker way? Can I avoid the binning of the data and take advantage of the fact that a) my filter is finite in size (just a box) and b) I have a list of time points. Thus, I just have to check whether my time points are currently part of the sliding box, or not.

So, I am looking for a solution that has complexity O(d*n) with d the size of the resolution of the convolution. Thus, I want to be much faster than O(b**2) with b the number of bins. Moreover, since n << b, it still holds that O(d*n) is much less than O(b * log b) for fft based convolution.  Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions. This seems more mathematics/algorithm related and is therefore too broad for the scope of Stack Overflow. I would recommend posing this question to [MathSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/). Good question though.

Comment: Thanks, I am actually looking for an off-the-shelf solution in python and not necessarily for a general algorithmic advice. Maybe there's a package I don't know about. I mean you need stuff like this a lot in Neuroscience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convolutions with large box filters can be speed up using a [cumulative sum of the signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table):

**Example signal:**

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(10)
print a
```

Output:

```
[ 0.22501645  0.46078123  0.6788864   0.88293584  0.10379173  0.50422604
  0.4670648   0.22018486  0.96649785  0.44451671]
```

**Convolution using the [default convolution function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html):**

```
print np.convolve(a, np.ones(3) / 3, mode='valid')
```

Output:

```
[ 0.45489469  0.67420116  0.55520466  0.49698454  0.35836086  0.39715857
  0.55124917  0.54373314]
```

**Convolution using the cumulative sum:**

```
s = np.cumsum(np.concatenate(([0], a)))
print (s[3:] - s[:-3]) / 3
```

Output:

```
[ 0.45489469  0.67420116  0.55520466  0.49698454  0.35836086  0.39715857
  0.55124917  0.54373314]
```

---

Both the `cumsum` computation as well as the list subtraction are O(n) with n being the number of list elements, so the overall computing time is O(n) and - interestingly - independent of the filter size.

Comment: Neat, why do you have to concatenate 0 to the array a?

Comment: @SmCaterpillar: Only with an additional 0 you can get the correct results via subtracting lists - even for the very first element. E.g. `s[3] - s[0] = (0+a[0]+a[1]+a[2]) - 0 = a[0]+a[1]+a[2]`. ;)